# How does jQuery accomplish chaining of commands?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

I consider myself (at best) a mid-level JavaScript guy...and of course...I want to understand HOW some things are accomplished so I can write better code.  As such, I've been looking under-the-hood of jQuery trying to uderstand it a little more about how certain things are accomplished.

**For example:**
jQuery handles the case where IE and Opera return items by name instead of ID by doing the following:

```
// HANDLE: $("#id")
else 
{
    var elem = document.getElementById( match[3] );

    // Handle the case where IE and Opera return items
    // by name instead of ID
    if ( elem && elem.id != match[3] )
        return jQuery().find( selector );

    // Otherwise, we inject the element directly into the jQuery object
    var ret = jQuery( elem || [] )
    ret.context = document;
    ret.selector = selector;

    return ret;
}
```

...okay that's easy!

**But a typical line of jQuery code chains a series of commands together:**

```
$('#someElementId').fadeIn().css({ ...Some CSS Properties ... });
```

Now...I 'think' the chaining portion is handled in the following area:

```
jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function() { ... };
```

I'm combing through this area...and I see HOW a **single** command is processed...but I don't really see WHERE or HOW a **chain-of-commands** are managed.  So I am obviously missing something.

**So My Question Is:**

1. How does jQuery implement chaining of selectors?

Comment: Each method returns the current or modified selection object. It's called Fluent Interface style.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#JavaScript

Comment: Okay...that's cool.  But can you please show AND explain where this is going on in the jQuery code?

Comment: The link has examples in multiple languages, including javascript.

Comment: Okay...I see.  If you identify WHERE this happens in the code and put it into an answer below (and maybe add some commenting) then I can credit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment:

This is from the example here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#JavaScript
With extra comments

```
var Car = function() {

        var speed, color, doors;

        this.setSpeed = function(speed) {
                this.speed = speed;
                **//Returns the reference to the calling `car` object** 
                return this; 
        };

        this.setColor = function(color) {
                this.color = color;
                **//Returns the reference to the calling `car` object** 
                return this; 
        };

        this.setDoors = function(doors) {
                this.doors = doors;
                **//Returns the reference to the calling `car` object** 
                return this; 
        };

};

// Fluent interface
**//Each method returns a reference to the object itself**
**//so the next method chain is refering back to the previous returned value**
**//ie - itself, the orginal object that started the call chain**
myCar = new Car();
myCar.setSpeed(100).setColor('blue').setDoors(5);

// Example without fluent interface
**// normal, non fluent style, where each method returns Void**
**// so you need to start with the object reference yourself each time**
myCar2 = new Car();
myCar2.setSpeed(100);
myCar2.setColor('blue');
myCar2.setDoors(5);
```

Comment: In your example snippet from jQuery, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8431708/426894

Comment: @PrisonerZERO Open the jQuery source in your browser, type Ctrl+F, then type `return this`.  It is happening on all the lines that get highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

All the methods on a `jQuery` object will return a `jQuery` object.

In this particular example you can see them being created `jQuery().find( selector )` and `jQuery( elem || [] )`

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain with an example. For this example you should open chrome developer console or firebug.

```
var $m = function() {
    return this;
};
$m.log = function(param) {
    console.log(param);
    return this;
};
$m.alert = function(param) {
    this.log('alerting: ' + param);
    alert(param);
    return this;
};
$m.log('start').alert('Sample message').log('end').log('success');
```

As you can see, every function returns `this`, which refers to `$m` for this example. This way I can chain as many methods as I want.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is this: Jquery functions return a reference to the relevant object when they execute, which is what allows you to chain operations together. So, if you perform an operation to find a div, the function returns a reference, allowing you to immediately chain another operation to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Using *return this;* returns the parent OBJECT

```
var myObject = {
  a: function(){
    alert('a');
    return this; 
    //this == myObject, so returning myObject means 
    //the next function in the chain will call myObject.___
  },
  b: function(){
    alert('b');
    return this;
  }
}
myObject.a().b();//alerts 'a' then alerts 'b'
```