# How does jQuery chain functions while still returning an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Having read

[How does jQuery accomplish chaining of commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431615/how-does-jquery-accomplish-chaining-of-commands)
and
[how does jquery chaining work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work)

I am still left to wonder how something like this is possible in jQuery

```
var a = $('body')
// a returns [<body></body>], an array.

a.click()
// Seems like this should return an error if a returns an array, not a function.
```

The linked SO answers have only told me how to do things like

```
a.b().c()
```

It's the `a()` I still don't understand. I understand that chaining works by returning `this` but then how does it also return an array by itself?

Comment: jQuery doesn't return an array.  It returns a jQuery object.  It just pretends to be an array.  It's an "array-like" object.

Comment: there are a few tricks for "upgrading" an array, either page-wide or on a per-instance basis.

Comment: Would you provide an example of this fake array, upgrading of an array as an answer, please?

Comment: `var x = {"length": 0, splice: Array.prototype.splice}; console.log(x); // []` x is still an object, but it can appear and act like an array depending on how you use it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261670/what-makes-a-jquery-object-show-up-as-an-array-in-chromes-developer-tools and https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-7/array-like-objects

Comment: Basically, if an object has `length` and `splice` properties, then Chrome will show it as an array in the console, even though it's not an array.  If you use `console.dir` instead of `console.log`, then you'll see what it really is.

Comment: Looks like I posted a dupe. Shame on me. Thank you, everyone.

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate as the only difference between this question and the linked duplicate is that you (mistakenly) thought jQuery was returning an array. This was addressed by the top comment.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz: google for "subclassing array js", "extending Array.prototype", and "proxy array js". you can bring array methods to a custom Constructor's instances, or bring custom methods to Array.prototype. jQuery wasn't in the position to mod prototype, but individual projects might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the jQuery source code viewer site the definition for $ (http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.9.1&fn=$) is as follows:

**$**

```
function (selector, context) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery);
}
```

Notice it is returning from init(). Inside of init (http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.9.1&fn=init) we see that at the end it calls a function called makeArray:

**init**

```
function (selector, context, rootjQuery) {
    var match, elem;

// rest of function defintion

    return jQuery.makeArray(selector, this);
}
```

Which brings us to the answer to the question 'How does jQuery chain functions while still returning an array?'

makeArray (http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.9.1&fn=jQuery.makeArray) looks like this:

**makeArray**

```
function (arr, results) {
    var ret = results || [];

    if (arr != null) {
        if (isArraylike(Object(arr))) {
            jQuery.merge(ret, typeof arr === "string" ? [arr] : arr);
        } else {
            core_push.call(ret, arr);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I've been pouring over the jQuery code and couldn't make sense of the path it takes until now. Thank you.